# Fetching the window.location.pathname with a Pound Sign in the URL - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my webpage I have a list of articles that I hide and show depending on which link a user clicks

```
<a id="sports" href="#">Sports</a>
<a id="weather" href="#">Weather</a>
```

When I link a person to my site with the `id` of the article appended to the URL, I want to fire a click event on that same `<a>` element

For example, if the URL shared is

```
http://mywebpage.com/page-1/#/weather
```

This event should be fired after the page loads, something like this:

```
if(linkInUrl === 'weather') $("a#weather").trigger("click");
```

So my question is, how can I get `linkInUrl`?  I know `window.location.pathname` will get the path after the .com, but it doesn't fetch whatever is after the `/#/`. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `window.location.hash` to retrieve the value in the URL. You simply then need to remove the `/` and you can select the element by that id and raise a click event on it:

```
if (window.location.hash) {
  var target = window.location.hash.replace('/', '');
  $('#' + target).trigger('click');
}
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help